# How to get GET method parameters by laravel 5

Tags: php, nginx, laravel-5

I tried to make these code.
then I send below request uri
http://192.168.33.10/api/v1/company?data=test
but, it can't get data parameter.
Do you know how to get it?

Route.php

```
$api = app('Dingo\Api\Routing\Router');
$api->version('v1', function ($api) {
/* API */
$api->group(['prefix' => 'v1',
    'before' => 'v1',
    'middleware' => 'cors',
    'namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers',
    'domain' => '192.168.33.10'
],function ($api) {
    // get company list
    $api->get('/company/', "CompaniesController@index");
});
});
```

controller.php

```
   public function index(UsersCreateRequest $request)
   {
    var_dump($request->input('data'));
    $users = $this->repository->all();

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $users,
    ]);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

`input` method returns data of the form inputs. To get the query parameters you should use the `query` method:

```
var_dump($request->query('data'));
```

Comment: Thank you for ask me about it.
I try to write it. but It still not get parameter.
strange point is that I also try to write $_REQUEST['data'] and $_GET['data'] 

But I can't get parameter. Do you know another resolution?

Comment: If you send the request through a browser it may not work, coz of `cors`, try to send the request with `postman`.

Comment: To be honest, I'm using postman now.
Should I add header parameter or something?

Comment: Maybe postman is not sending those parameters? try to check its settings

Comment: Uhmm, according to write var_dump($request), I can find out this parameter . When I check about [REQUEST_URI], it write  "/api/v1/company?data=test"

When I set it by postman, I select [params] button and add data parameter and set url only.

Comment: Uhmm, according to add var_dump($_REQUEST), I can't find parameter.
I expect to have another cause. Maybe, PHP setting or Nginx setting.
Do you have any ideas?