# How to get get method parameter by nginx and php

Tags: php, nginx

I can't get to get method parameter now.
According to survey, I notice to php can't get to get parameter by php.
Do you know this resolution?
I think to cause is Nginx or php setting.

Nginx setting is bellow setting.

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  localhost;
#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /var/www/html/startup_intern/public;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "localhost:3001";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Accept,Authorization,Cache-Control,Content-Type,DNT,If-Modified-Since,Keep-Alive,Origin,User-Agent,X-Mx-ReqToken,X-Requested-With';
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /var/www/html/startup_intern/public;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
#
location ~ \.php$ {
    # root           html;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #fastcgi_pass   /var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /var/www/html/startup_intern/public/$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
}
```

Comment: "I notice to php can't get to get parameter by php" I'm so confused. Could you show us an example of "get method parameter" along with your PHP codes that  trying to do that?

Comment: Oh, sorry for that. OK, I write it.
It's too simple. I'm using to Laravel So, I try to write Laravel's index.php
below code. But I can't get some parameter.

URL:http://192.168.33.10/company/?email=testdata&company=test2

var_dump($_GET);
var_dump($_REQUEST);

Comment: You said you can't get some parameter, then what's the result on your end?Which is missing?

Comment: Right. Uhmm, no idea. I posted this question. but I couldn't get tips.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40299000/how-to-get-get-method-parameters-by-laravel-5

That's why, I'm suspecting to nginx setting or php setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a problem with your nginx configuration. The line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
```

has a bug. Nginx documentation says that the try_files directive is used to try the given urls in order. If the first one succeeds then it is returns, otherwise the next url is checked. (http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files). In your case the first url is $uri without query parameters. If you switch the order of your urls then your php script should be able to access the query string. You can try the following:

```
try_files /index.php$query_string $uri $uri/;
```